# Appending basis elements to a basis in topology.

Tags: general-topology

I know in linear algebra, once we have a set of basis vectors, adding any vector to the basis causes the set to no longer be a basis, because of the loss of linear independence. However in topology, once there is a basis for a topology, can we always append another open set to the basis, and have it still be a basis?

For example the collection of open intervals $(a,b), a<b, a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is a basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. However,if we add any open set to this collection, does this new subset of elements from the topology still form a basis?

Would the collection of all open intervals as well as $\mathbb{R}$ itself be a basis?

Would the collection of all open intervals as well as all open rays still be a basis?

What about the collection of open intervals, along with the empty set?

I would presume attaching open sets to any basis does not disturb the collection from being a basis, because of the definition of a basis for a specific topology.

Comment: Yes: if $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for a topology $\tau$, and $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$, then $\mathscr{B}\cup\mathscr{U}$ is a base for $\tau$.

Comment: Yes, maybe the name 'basis' is a bit overloaded and it's not a perfect match here with the same term of linear algebra. The term 'generating system' (of open sets) might be a bit better analogy.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can add any number of open sets to a base for $(X,\tau)$ and we still have a base; we don't have to use these extra sets, nor is there any notion of independence: it's actually rather special when we can even find a base that is *minimal*, i.e. where we cannot leave out any set and still have a base (this happens for finite spaces and discerte spaces e.g.) but usually there will be more than one way to write an open set as a union of basic open sets,a nd that's never an issue. So the analogy with vector space bases is quite weak.

All the examples you mention are indeed other bases for $\Bbb R$. Note that bases don't often include the empty set as it does not contribute to any union, and we can always leave it out anyway (or add it too, as I said).